# Clarification on comparative constructions is needed

Tags: grammar, word-order, comparative-constructions, particle-より

Here's a sentence:

> シベリア**より**東の地域はシベリアの中部ほど寒くないです。

I understand what it says but I don't understand why 「より」 is used right after 「シベリア」, and why the word order is not like this:

> シベリア**の**東の地域はシベリアの中部ほど寒くないです。

Can the reason be in those 2 different comparative constructions in one sentence? I assume that one cannot say something like 「AよりBほどC」, thus involving 「AはBほどC」to make it work properly.

Even if it's right, I'd like to know the reason 「シベリアより」 is even taking place and, what's more, I'd like to know how to translate it properly. Every time I read it I want to say "Comparing to Siberia, eastern region is not that cold, as central one", but then again, "comparing to Siberia" just makes no sense for me. Also, I cannot understand why author used this, but not the **「シベリアの東の・・・」**.

Comment: Aより東 means 'east of A', not the eastern part of A. This should be more evident if you show the source, which I assume is: https://rhinospike.com/audio_requests/per_iocum/8150/#recordings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you actually stumble over is this expression:

> シベリアより東の地域 *region(s) to the east of Siberia*

Here シベリアより東（だ） is a noun predicate that modifies 地域, and this より has nothing to do with the rest of the sentence.

～より東 (lit. "more east than"?) may be a strange wording to European languages speakers, but it's a sound phrase in Japanese to describe what's at removes from a location in eastern direction (as opposed to being the east end of the location). Similarly:

> ～より上 "above; higher than"
>   ～より下 "below; lower than"
>   ～より左 "to the left of"
>   ～より右 "to the right of"

If you reword them using ～**の**左 etc. it'll usually  be understood as "next to it to the left".

So,

> シベリアより東の地域はシベリアの中部ほど寒くないです。
>   *Regions to the east of Siberia are not as cold as central Siberia.*